# Can't manage to display form from my view

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to create a page where admins can upload some files using some `FileField`. The problem is that I can't manage to display any field from my form, I must be missing something important but I can't find out what, hope anyone can help me.

Here is the code related to this form:

**urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^admin_fichiers_phyto/$', phyto_views.AdminFichiersPhyto.as_view(), name='phyto-admin-fichiers-phyto'), 
)
```

**phyto_admin_fichiers.html**

```py
{% block forms %}

{% if user.is_staff%}

    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <span>{{ form.other }}</span>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <p>
     <input id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Synchronisation Autre" name="autre"/>
     <input id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Synchronisation Traitements généraux" name="trtm_gen"/>
    </p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```py
class AdminFichiersPhyto(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'phyto/phyto_admin_fichiers.html'
    form_class = forms.PhytoFileForm
    current_url = 'phyto-files'
    context_object_name = 'phyto_files'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.POST.get('autre'):
            return HttpResponse('<h1>autre</h1>')
        if request.POST.get('trtm_gen'):
            return HttpResponse('<h1>Traitement Generaux</h1>')
```

**forms.py**

```py
class PhytoFileForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = models.PhytoFile
        fields = ['general_treatment', 'other']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PhytoFileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**models.py**

```py
class PhytoFile(models.Model):
    general_treatment = models.FileField(upload_to='fichiers_phyto/', blank=True, null=True)
    other = models.FileField(upload_to='fichiers_phyto/', blank=True, null=True)
```

Here is what my webpage is showing :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMT4p.jpg

I can't understand why the Field isn't displayed, I really hope somebody have the knowledge to help me with my problem ! ^_^

Have a nice day ! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several major issues here.

TemplateView doesn't know anything about `form_class` (or `context_object_name`, for that matter). And by defining `post` like that you've avoided actually doing anything with the uploaded data. You need to use a view that deals with forms; in your case, a CreateView would be ideal. Inside that view, that response code needs to go in `form_valid`.

Secondly, PhytoFileForm needs to inherit from `forms.ModelForm`; a standard Form class doesn't know anything about models and doesn't use a Meta class. However, since you're not customizing the form beyond the field selection, you can just rely on the automatic form created by CreateView.

Next, your template is broken; it doesn't have an HTML form element. Also, since your form class has two fields but you only display one on the template, the form will never be valid.

So, putting it together:

```
class AdminFichiersPhyto(CreateView):
    template_name = 'phyto/phyto_admin_fichiers.html'
    model = models.PhytoFile

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        if request.POST.get('autre'):
            return HttpResponse('<h1>autre</h1>')
        if request.POST.get('trtm_gen'):
            return HttpResponse('<h1>Traitement Generaux</h1>')
```

```
{% block forms %}

{% if user.is_staff%}

  <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <span>{{ form.other }}</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>{{ form. general_treatment }}</span>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <p>
     <input id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Synchronisation Autre" name="autre"/>
     <input id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Synchronisation Traitements généraux" name="trtm_gen"/>
    </p>
  </form>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'm quite new to django's front part and I used a friend's files to see how he displayed some forms. I will try everything you told me and understand everything of it and I will let you know if I managed to fix my issue !

Comment: Thank you very much it worked ! I just had to add `fields = ['general_treatment', 'other']` in my view. You really helped me out, thanks again !